# Dataloader CLI gets stuck on ignoring fields

Tags: data-loader

I am getting a weird error when trying to upload a CSV to SalesForce. It looks like the CLI gets stuck in ignoring certain fields that are not mapped in my SDL file (see image). Did anyone ever experience such an error?

[image]

Comment: Hi i don't think this is an error but more an INFO message